# Laravel - Login on any page

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

When I check out the Laravel docs and tutorials for user login they all have a separate login.php view to handle this.  I am learning how to create an e-commerce/shopping cart site.  What I want to do is have a sidebar showing the login form on every page the non-logged-in user visits.

I am confused on how to route this because of the global nature of the login section.

```
//AccountController.php

class AccountController extends BaseController {

public function signIn()
{
    $rules = array(
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=> 'required'
        );

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validation->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->with('message','Incorrect username and/or password');
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }
    else{

        $user = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

                    // login user
        Auth::attempt($user)
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
 }
```

This is the form in my views:

```
//views/layouts/master.blade.php

{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'AccountController@signIn')) }}
{{ Form::label('email', 'Email address: ') }} 
{{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email')) }}
<br />
{{ Form::label('password','Password') }}
{{ Form::password('password') }}
<br />
{{ Form::submit('Login', array('class'=> 'btn btn-info')) }}
{{Form::close() }}
```

What would be the correct way to set up the route for this form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```php
Route::post('/signin', 'AccountController@signIn');
```

And, to check if the user is currently logged in and, if he/she's not, show the login form, your form could be changed to:

```
@if( ! Auth::check())
    {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'AccountController@signIn')) }}
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email address: ') }} 
        {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email')) }}
        <br />
        {{ Form::label('password','Password') }}
        {{ Form::password('password') }}
        <br />
        {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class'=> 'btn btn-info')) }}
    {{Form::close() }}
@endif
```

Comment: I used your route and it is working for the most part.  I don't understand how the '/signin' parameter makes the route work.  Additionally I have tried to login from several pages and I am able to login but it always directs me back to the home page.  Should I use something other than Redirect::back()?

Comment: Routes are basically definition of your urls, so `/signin` is the url `http://yourserver.dev/signin` and Route::post() tells Laravel to expect a POST method sent to that url. Redirect::back() should get you back to the URL where you were.

Comment: So '/signin' is a "dummy" url...  and even though I do not have a signin view its alright because I redirect back to my previous page in the controller.  Thus allowing me to use the form on any page?  And Redirect::back() is working properly now.